# rendering react links from JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, server-side-rendering

Is there a way to get react links from JSON file? for example from:

```
const data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            paragraph: `Some text <Link to="/main-page">main page</Link> some text.`
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            paragraph: `Some text <Link to="/main-page">main page</Link> some text.`
        },
        
    ];

const App = () => ( 
        {data.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: item.paragraph
                }}>
                </p>
            </div>
        ))}
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

dangerouslySetInnerHTML works only for HTML tags and is not helping in this case

Comment: Why not just store the link title and path as attributes, then iterate over it, and render each link component properly. It would be much safer, and neater.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no other way and this is the data you must process, you can use regular expression in order to extract this info from the text and then re-create the `Link`

```js
let paragraph = 'Some text <Link to="/main-page">main page</Link> some text.'
console.log('Link text ==>', paragraph.match(/(?<=>)[^<]+/)[0])
console.log('Link target ==>', paragraph.match(/(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/)[2])
```

although, the best solution is the one Lissy93
noted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but you can import

the json file change the data to an Object and use it

but first you need to install json-loader and load the data anywhere you will like it

```
   export default {
    "data" : "data"
    }

import someData from './someData' 

const arr = [someDta.json()];

return (<div>
            {arr.map(item => {
              {paragraph: `Some text <Link to="/main-page">{{item .data}}</Link> some text.`}   
            })} 

       </div>
)
```